# I keep getting too many links from scraped website

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm scraping information from the table on the given website. It returns me the length of 184 even though there are only 180 links in the table

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup //importing stuff
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen

site = "http://www.voltwo.webd.pl/1-indexy/index-5-opracowania/01-maturalne-KINEMATYKA.html"
hdr = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
req = Request(site, headers=hdr)
page = urlopen(req)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, features="html5lib")
table = soup.find(id='table1') //id of the table in website

links = []

for link in table.findAll('a'):
    links.append(link.get('href')) //the length of links should be 180, and it's 184
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like the urls you're after are all pdf files but you also get `index.php` as one of the results.

So, just filter out those anchors that you want and there you have your 180 results.

Here's how:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "http://www.voltwo.webd.pl/1-indexy/index-5-opracowania/01-maturalne-KINEMATYKA.html"
page = requests.get(url).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "html.parser").find_all("td")

anchors = [a.find("a")["href"] for a in soup if a.find("a") and "pdf" in a.find("a")["href"]]
print(len(anchors))
```

Output: `180`